# Execute command using cypress (cy.exec) in another folder gives error

Tags: cypress

When I try to execute the command using Cypress. The exec for wormhole gives error

```
const rubyCommand = 'wormhole fbd-development bundle exec cucumber features/feature_files/create-package/new-fbd-package.feature:8';
    cy.exec(`cd /Users/username/Desktop/pcs-tests`)
    cy.wait(500)
    cy.exec(`wormhole fbd-development bundle exec cucumber features/feature_files/create-package/new-fbd-package.feature:8`, { failOnNonZeroExit: false })
        // cy.exec(`cd /Users/username/Desktop/pcs-tests && ${rubyCommand}`, { failOnNonZeroExit: false })
        .then((result) => {
            // Check if the Ruby script executed successfully
            if (result.code === 0) {
                cy.log('Ruby function executed successfully');
            } else {
                cy.log('Ruby function execution failed');
                cy.log('Error message: ' + result.stderr);
            }
        });
```

> Error: Error message: zsh:1: command not found: wormhole